# NATO tool link shortcut

Tags: script, hyperlinks, 10k-tools

This is a basic userscript which saves one click and some waiting time.

If you are anxious like me and don't like to head over to the (10k) Tools page, wait for the page to load while chasing the elusive link to the NATO tool - then this script is for you! It will add a direct link to the tool from the review queues dropdown - where the current Tools link is:

[image]

There's a [GitHub page](https://github.com/tomerkal/NATO-shortcut) and you can simply use [this link](https://%20https://github.com/tomerkal/NATO-shortcut/raw/main/NATOshort.user.js) to install.

---

This is a very simple and basic script which was my excuse to write my first userscript so I decided to share it in case anyone might also find it useful :)